# MuchRandomly Content-Type is not getting seen by a .Net Framework WebAPI server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-4.8, asp.net-web-api-routing

Documenting a much random issue, probably of .NetFramework, that happens once every 3-4 weeks.

We have 3 load-balanced servers in AWS behind ALB. And occassionally, one of the WebAPI servers stops seeing the **Content-Type** header and infers it to be **application/octet-stream**.

This is the **Good Server** that says that the Content-Type **application/asdf** is invalid.
[image: Good Server showing proper error]

This is the **Faulty Server** that says the the no Content-Type header was sent, so it is inferring it to be application/octed-stream. Please Note that through Postman, I am sending the Content-Type header as **application/asdf** which is simply getting ignored.

[image: Faulty Server showing Content-Type isn't sent and has to be inferred]

Please **note** that this has nothing to do with AWS ALB as I have checked this from the localmachine using curl as well. Response is the same.

[image: This is the JsonMediaformatterConfiguration that works properly once I restart the IIS process]

Comment: Why are you asking a question that has nothing to do with code, and that you already know the answer to? You know which server is problematic, fix or replace it.

Comment: @IanKemp The problem is either the code or the infrastructure as the FaultyServer starts working properly once IIS service is restarted. And the GoodServers turns faulty every 2/3 months.